# How can I remove a folder without a name in Win7?

Tags: windows-7

I use Windows 7. The problem can be seen from the picture. I have tried to remove the folder "by mouse". But I failed to do so. How can I remove the folder without a name?

[image]

UPDATE: Thanks to Nifle's answer, I got the following results:
[image]

Comment: I'm really confused that why I got this kind of folder suddenly.

Comment: It probably has a name using Unicode characters that don't show up in the chinese codepage. You could probably have deleted it from Explorer - or, selecting a truetype font and hitting "tab" from the command line to autocomplete [like "rmdir <tab>"]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It probably has a name that you just can't see.

Try `dir /x` *This displays the short names generated for non-8dot3 file names. The format is that of /N with the short name inserted before the long name. If no short name is present, blanks are displayed in its place.*

More info type `help dir` or go [here](http://www.computerhope.com/dirhlp.htm)

Then when you have that name use the `rmdir` or `rd` command to delete the directory. (Or `del` if it's an invisible file)

Comment: Hmm, I have tried it. And I saw the name `99A4~1`. What should I do then?

Comment: @Jack Have you tried `del 99A4~1`?

Comment: I tried `del 99A4~1` and confirmed deleting. But the folder is still there.

Comment: @Jack - Sorry out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: @Jack - Another idea. Can you rename it? `rename 99A4~1 foo` and then try to delete the dir `foo`.

Comment: @Nifle: The proper command to remove a folder in Windows is `rmdir`. `del folder` just deletes the files in the folder. @Jack: Try `rmdir 99A4~1`.

Comment: @Dennis - Thanks for pointing out my mistake

Comment: @Dennis, @Nifle: It's done now! Thanks. Actually `rd 994A~1` can also work. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you boot from a Linux Live CD (e.g. [Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)) and try deleting the folder.

After booting, go to `Applications > Places` and click on Home Folder to open Nautilus (i.e. the File Explorer for Ubuntu). Then check if the folder is visible and try to delete it with the right click menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm a user of Windows and I know nothing about Linux... What would you like to suggest me to do then?

Comment: You can download a linux "live" image for free, and use it without damaging your Windows partitions.  Burn it to a disc, boot to it, and then give it a try.

Comment: When he boots the live-cd, then what does he do?

Comment: He goes to `Applications >  Places` and clicks on `Home Folder` to open Nautilus (i.e. the File Explorer for Ubuntu). Then he checks if the folder is visible and tries to delete it with right click menu.

Comment: Good. Now put that in the answer and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dir /x`, keep going in the structure (as you go along rename this dirs. to something simpler by copying and pasting their old dos names and putting "CRAP" instead, like this REN 99A4~1 CRAP)

You will get to a point where you can no longer go further, but there are more files.

Use windows explorer this time to drill down the folders until you get told you have not got permissions, use the security tab and take ownership of the directory and all its sub directories.)

You can now delete the lot.

No need to boot with Linux.